# quotient of a hyperplane by the action of cyclic group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, general-topology, algebraic-topology

let $H=\{(x,y,-x-y)\in \mathbb C^3\}$ and let $S^3$ the unit sphere in $H$. Why the following is true :

> The linear action of $\mathbb Z_3$ on $S^3$ is free and  $H/\mathbb Z_3=C(M)$ the cone on $M$ where $M=S^3/\mathbb Z_3$ is a three-manifold
>    (the apex at the origine and the cone extending to $\infty$)

Here $\mathbb Z_3$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_3$ acting by permuting coordinates.

Comment: What action of $\mathbb Z_3$?

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: $\mathbb Z_3$ acts by permuting coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean $S_3$? Else you'd have to specify *how* $\mathbb Z_3$ permutes the coordinates.

Comment: @ joriki : $\mathbb Z_3$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ generated by $(123)$

Comment: @palio: That still doesn't specify the action. It was already clear that only this subgroup of $S_3$ is isomorphic $\mathbb Z_3$, but you need to specify one of the two possible isomorphisms. By the way, people don't get pinged if you put a space between the '@' and the name.

Comment: @joriki : i'm not sure i understand what you mean by two possible isomorphisms! but the action is as follows: the generator $(123)$ takes $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(x_2,x_3,x_1)$ and more generally a permutation $\sigma $ takes $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to  $(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(3)})$

Comment: @palio: I think we're talking past each other because you're considering these as abstract groups and I was thinking of $\mathbb Z_3$ as a concrete group $\{0,1,2\}$ that can be mapped to the subgroup generated by $(123)$ in two different ways, with $1$ mapped either to $(123)$ or to $(132)$. The distinction is irrelevant for your purposes.

Comment: @joriki : yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: Palio, please edit the question text to include a description of the actionyou have in mind: it is always best if the reader does not need to read all the comments to see what you are really asking.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: ok i will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $S^3 = \{(x,y,-y-x)\mid |x|^2+|y|^2 + |x+y|^2 = 1\}$.  Since the action of $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$ permutes the coordinates, it's clear that $G$ preserves $S^3$.  Now, suppose $e\neq g\in G$ and that $g(x,y,-y-x) = (x,y,-y-x)$.  Then in particular, we also have $g^2(x,y,-y-x) = (x,y,-y-x)$.  It follows that we must have $x = y = -y-x$ and from this it follows that the fixed point was $(0,0,0)$, which is not an element of $S^3$.

Note that this proof doesn't use the fact that we're looking at the *unit* sphere, only that the sphere has nonzero radius.

Next, notice that $H \cong C(S^3) = S^3\times[0,\infty)/$~ where ~ collapses all of $S^3\times\{0\}$ to a point.  The map establishing this homemorphism can be defined as follows:  Every non $0$ point $q$ in $H$ determines a unique ray emanating from $0$.  This ray will pierce the sphere $S^3$ in precisely one point $f(q)$.  Now, map $H$ to $C(S^3)$ by sending $q$ to $(f(q), |q|^2)$ if $q\neq 0$ and sending $0$ to $S^3\times\{0\}$.  I leave it to you to prove this is a homeomorphism.

Further, this homemorphism is $G$ equivariant if $G$ acts on $C(S^3)$ by simply copying the $G$ action on each $S^3$.  That is, $g(p, t) = (gp, t)$.  (Again, I leave this to you to prove).  This should easily allow you to construct a homeomorphism from $H/G \cong C(S^3)/G$ to $C(S^3/G)$.

Comment: DeVito: Thank you!! we can see that $H\cong \mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$ so can we say some thing for more general $H$ and $G$ : if $H$ is subspace homeomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$ on which a group $G$ acts equivariantly then  $H/G$ is homeo to $C(S/G)$ where $S$ is the sphere in $H$?

Comment: @palio:  You'd need to know 2 additional facts:  1.  that $G$ acts linearly and 2.  that $G$ preserves the spheres in some metric.  When $G$ is a finite (or more generally, compact), then 2. is automatic.  It's hard to find something *not* satisfying 1, but they do exist (even for finite groups I believe - I think there's a weird action of $\mathbb{Z}_2 on \mathbb{R}^6$ which isn't conjugate to a linear action though it preserves all spheres.)